# Check that the variable user have been Inputted is either String or not in Java : setter & getter?

Tags: java

I was practicing setter & getter in Java. I thought what if my code will through an error if user have set Employee name incorrect i.e. "123" or "@qre23" which can't be someone's name in real .Here is my code, suggest me what to upgrade ?

```
class MyEmployee {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void getName(){
        System.out.println("\n Your Employee Name is : " + this.name);
    }


}


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyEmployee myEmployee = new MyEmployee();
        myEmployee.setName("209");
        myEmployee.getName();

    }
}
```

Comment: Just use a normal regex pattern to validate your input

Comment: check java pattern class. it is responsible for handling regex operations
https://www.baeldung.com/regular-expressions-java

Comment: Can you code it please ?

Comment: May I suggest that names are much more complex than you seem to think. Don't forget when Prince changed his name (officially) to an unpronounceable symbol.

Answer (score 2):

Match the string with the Regex using `matches()`

```
 public void setName(String name){
        if(name.matches("^[a-zA-Z ]*$"))
          this.name = name;
        else
          //throw error
    }
```

Comment: In this case while i am doing this -->> ``` myEmployee.setName("Arpit Jana"); ```   it shows null

Comment: Otherwise without space it is working well.

Comment: Try now. I added a space to the regex expression

Comment: I wouldn't filter names.

Comment: And what if the name involves Chinese characters?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in many different ways depending on what regex you want but this is one way to do it. Also make sure your getter returns a name. Right now, your getter doesn't return the name.

```
class MyEmployee {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    public void setName(String name){
        String regx = "^[\\p{L} .'-]+$";
        boolean match = Pattern.matches(regx, name);
        if(match){
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    public String getName(){
        System.out.println("\n Your Employee Name is : " + this.name);
        return this.name;
    }
}
```